# Transfer photos from friends windows 10 pc to my iphone

Tags: photos

I am wanting to get photos that a friend has on their computer to transfer across to my iPhone. My friend does not use apple products and does not have iTunes, and I don't want to set up iTunes on their computer or wipe my existing information.

any suggestions?

Comment: Dropbox, Google Photos, email... Read more here: https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-transfer-photos-from-computer-to-iphone-without-itunes/. Also make sure to check answers here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18262/is-there-an-airdrop-client-for-microsoft-windows

Answer (score 1):

You can try to sign in iCloud.com on your friend's computer, click on Photos icon, and upload photos to iCloud. Hours or days later it will sync with your iPhone if you connect WIFI. Then you can get photos to your iPhone without wiping any existing information.